Ubuntu Server 20.04 Java mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar in PATH to connect to mysql database from java app main
I am having problems with Glassfish 4.1 connecting to a mysql database. Ive checked that the database can be logged into with root and password. When the web app gets called Glassfish consistently says :
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I have written a small app that needs to test if java can successfully connect to mysql before I can fault find any further. My question is how do I put the mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar (/home/glassfish/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar) in the users path before I execute the app which will refer to the driver to connect to the mysql database. Must I do something like this which does not work :
# MYSQL CONNECTOR ON PATH
export MSQLCONNECTOR_HOME=/home/glassfish/glassfish4/glassfish/lib
echo $MSQLCONNECTOR_HOME
# set PATH global VARIABLE ADD *_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:MSQLCONNECTOR_HOME


The error message that you report
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Comes from MySQL, so the driver is properly loaded and connection established, but Access is denied (or rather, not Granted with user root from localhost). You can check the connection properties and / or the JDBC's URL that you are using.
User root, sounds like that you are running MySQL as the root Linux user, can you confirm or are you trying to connect to MySQL with the root user? (Both are bad practice, you should not use root user for running your apps/process - if not explicitly required and we'll know - and/or not using MySQL root user to access to your DB).
